# Variational Expectation of Poisson

Tags: gpflow

I was wondering where the analytical form of the variational Expectation
\int q(f)logp(y|f) df for the Poisson Likelihood comes from (when using a log link).

In the documentation it is only mentioned that one can approximate the intractable likelihood,
however I'm not familiar enough with the topic to know what exactly is used.

```
    let g(.) be the inverse-link function, then this likelihood represents

    p(y_i | f_i) = Poisson(y_i | g(f_i) * binsize)

    Note:binsize
    For use in a Log Gaussian Cox process (doubly stochastic model) where the
    rate function of an inhomogeneous Poisson process is given by a GP.  The
    intractable likelihood can be approximated by gridding the space (into bins
    of size 'binsize') and using this Poisson likelihood.
```

Could you maybe point me to that approximation method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variational_expectations is the method on the Likelihood class that gets used when GPflow is doing approximate (variational) inference. The likelihood isn't being approximated per-se, but the variational method is approximating the posterior, and in doing so computes the ELBO, of which one part is variational_expectations.

It computes

E_{q(f_n)} [ log p(y_n | f_n) ]

Where q(f_n) is a Gaussian with mean/variance Fmu/Fvar. For the Poisson Likelihood with log/exp link, we have (ignoring binsize):

log p(y_n | f_n) = poisson(y_n, exp(f_n))

which is equal to

y_n * tf.log(tf.exp(f_n)) - exp(f_n) - tf.lgamma(y_n + 1.)

To compute the expectation, we need to know the expectation of f_n (since log(exp(f_n)) = f_n) and the expectation of exp(f_n). Those are mu and exp(mu + var / 2). Plugging that in gives

E_{q(f_n)} [ log p(y_n | f_n) ] = y_n * mu_n - exp(mu_n + var_n/2) - tf.lgamma(y_n + 1.)

Which is what is implemented in the Poisson class's variational_expectations method.

Comment: Thanks, in hindsight it seems pretty obvious :)